# How to print short file urls in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, file, url

I want to achieve something similar to eslint output. Where file urls:

- look like `38:13  error`
- recognized as urls so I can click on them

[image]

I have tried different combinations of `pathToFileUrl` and URL methods but I always end up with some long url like `file:///some/long/absolute/path/to/file:10`

Comment: These are line and column numbers

Comment: I understand this. The thing is that it displays like line and column but it has the full file url encoded so when you click it you will navigate to this file.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminal-link

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284476/terminal-create-hyperlinks